# Existence of functions $g$ such that 1. $f\circ g(1) =2$; 2. $g \circ f(1) = 2$, for all $f$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Let $F$ be the sets of all functions from $S$ to $S$.

a) Prove or disprove the statement: "For all $f \in F$, there exists $g \in F$ so that $(f \circ g)(1) = 2$"

b) Prove or disprove the statement: "For all $f \in F$, there exists $g \in F$ so that $(g \circ f)(1) = 2$"

I think the first is true and the second false but I am unsure how to prove it.

Thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: Can you share with us your proof for the first one?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove it! I just drew an arrow diagram and I think it is correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: For the second one, you are looking for $g$ so that $g (f(1)) = 2$. Can you find one such function?

Comment: So for part a if g was 2x for example it would be true?

Comment: That depends on the value of $f(1)$. But you can make $g$ so that the value is always $2$, right?

Comment: How could i do that?

Comment: Set $g(x) = 2$, for example?

Comment: okay I see what you mean.  So in this case b is true because for any function f, if g(x) = 2, then f o g(1) = 2.

Comment: What is a function?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: and then a must be false because if f(x) = 4 then g o f(1) cannot equal 2

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f:S\to S$ given by $f(n)=1$ for $n=1,2,3,4$. Is it true that $a)$ holds?

Now, for $b)$, given any function $f\in F$, do you think that there exist $g\in F$ such that $g(f(1))=2$? Do you think you can construct it (if it exists)?